# Can a cell completely lose the ability to undergo apoptosis?

Tags: cancer, apoptosis

What I mean is - can a super-cancer cell completely lose the ability to kill itself, losing all apoptosis-related mechanisms and becoming eternally resistant to any drug that tries to induce apoptosis directly or indirectly.

Comment: It's not so much that a cancerous cell loses "the ability to kill itself". Rather, many cancers occur because there is a relative *lack of inhibition* of apoptosis. Many cancer drugs try to un-inhibit these apoptosis mechanisms. I think it is unlikely that a cell would be "resistant to any drug"; the problem with cancer treatment is that the drugs often kill healthy cells too, and there is a limit on the dose that can be given while keeping the patient alive. This may give the impression that the cancer is resistant, but it may just mean that the drug dose is too low.

Comment: Try reading The Hallmarks of Cancer and The Hallmarks of Cancer: The Next Generation by Hanahan and Weinberg. Both are Cell Reviews.